# insertar registros sin duplicar

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy haciendo la lectura de un archivo pendientes.xlsx con la Librería PHPExcel, y los registros se insertan en una tabla_temporal

Mi problema es que el archivo que estoy haciendo la lectura (pendientes.xlsx) se le agregan NUEVOS registros diarios.

ejemplo:

Día --- Total de registros --------- Registros Nuevos

Dia1 --- 50   -----

Dia2 --- 70 --- 20---

Cuando vuelvo a leer otra vez el archivo (pendientes.xlsx), se insertan todos los registros, y no quiero eso. Solo necesito que se inserte los 20 Registros Nuevos

Mi tabla en la BD cuenta con los siguientes campos: Id, Nombre, Ciudad, Nombre.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow, `N...` (a la espera de que te des un nombre). La pregunta no se entiende. Debes decir qué código usas y cómo funciona. Una posible solución sería ejecutar la consulta una vez al día, filtrando por la fecha actual, así sólo se insertarán los registros de cada día. Lo dejo sólo como idea, porque no dices absolutamente nada de la lógica o del contexto en el que debería funcionar el código.

Comment: ¿En tu tabla tienes dos campos llamados Nombre? Para poder ayudarte, por favor, envíanos una muestra de los datos que envías un día y otra de los que envías al día siguiente. ¿En la hoja de cálculo tienen algún tipo de identificador único para localizar los repetidos?

Comment: No me he equivocado el otro es País                                           Ejemplo del día 1                                                                          Id---------Nombre------- Cuidad---------País---------                                 1-------Juan Perez------México-------México-------                                     2--------Angel Perez.---C.Victoria----México------

Comment: Pero David lo he logrado agregandole un IGNORE al INSERT.     
 iNSERT IGNORE INTO tabla_temp y cuando cree la tabla coloque como PRIMARY KEY (Id,otro_campo).                               MUCHAS GRACIAS DAVID POR INTENTAR AYUDARME :3

Comment: Envíanos el SQL de esa tabla temporal con algún dato insertado y al hoja de cálculo con alguno de los datos que se insertarían de forma duplicada, alguno nuevo, y los INSERT que estás ejecutando. Vamos a ver qué está pasando.